# Sync Polly with timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, .net-4.8, polly, retry-logic

This code runs to the end, no `TimeoutRejectedException`.
If I change the strategy to `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic`, it will enter the executed logic twice, before throwing the `TimeoutRejectedException`.

What should I do, if I want to retry after a timeout with the retry policy? (if it does a timeout, I want to try again after a pause until I hit `MaxRetries`)?

Is the only solution to make my executing logic itself throw the timeout?
(The code is .net framework 4.8 and it made to run in LinqPad 5 and Polly v 8.3.1).

The `Optimistic` strategy does not seem to actually do anything in this setup, does it?

```
var retry = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Retry(1);

var timeout = Policy
    .Timeout(1, Polly.Timeout.TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);

var wrap = Policy.Wrap(retry, timeout);

try
{
    wrap
        .Execute(() =>
        {
            "Enter executed logic".Dump();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            "Exit executed logic".Dump();
        });
}
catch(TimeoutRejectedException ex)
{
    ex.Message.Dump();
}
```

Comment: *What should I do, if I want to retry after a timeout with the retry policy?* Because your retry is set up in a way to trigger for any exception that's why it is triggering for timeout as well (which throws a `TimeoutRejectedException`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic` because the `Thread.Sleep` does not use `CancellationToken` to interupt its waiting.

```
var retry = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Retry(1);

var timeout = Policy
    .Timeout(1, Polly.Timeout.TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);

var wrap = Policy.Wrap(retry, timeout);

try
{
    wrap
        .Execute(() =>
        {
            "Enter executed logic".Dump();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            "Exit executed logic".Dump();
        });
}
catch(TimeoutRejectedException ex)
{
    ex.Message.Dump();
}
```

Optimistic means that your to-be-decorated method can collaboratively cancel its work via a `CancellationToken`

```
var retry = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .Retry(1);

var timeout = Policy
    .Timeout(1, Polly.Timeout.TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic);

var wrap = Policy.Wrap(retry, timeout);

try
{
    wrap
        .Execute(token =>
        {
            "Enter executed logic".Dump();
            Task.Delay(5000, token).Wait(token);
            "Exit executed logic".Dump();
        }, CancellationToken.None);
}
catch(TimeoutRejectedException ex)
{
    ex.Message.Dump();
}
```

- Please note that in this case I've used a different overload of `Execute`.
- It is not mandatory to pass the `token` to both `Delay` and `Wait`

  - It is enough to pass only to the `Wait`: `Task.Delay(5000).Wait(token);`

Dotnet fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ei6iPA

Comment: The overload of Execute is an action, so that won't return a result.
But I got your solution to work in linqpad. Now I just need to get it to work in my real software.  Thanks!